# Close voters in the wrong voters' bucket?

Tags: bug

I voted to close/hold a question as "off topic", others voted for "unclear, what you are asking". Apparently I was the 5th and now I supposedly voted for "unclear" too. It's no big issue but it feels strange.

Is that on purpose or is it a bug?

see https://askubuntu.com/questions/382176/cant-open-my-documents

Answer (score 2):

Your vote was recorded correctly but most people voted for the reason given. To me that makes sense...

But I agree, it's different from past behaviour.

Comment: I agree that the close reason given should be the one the majority gave. I don't want to press another reason - it looks just strange to see my name there when I deliberately chose another reason :-)

Comment: Ummm... but when everybody votes OT each of the voters, has it's name besides the reason... apparently this doesn't happen with other close reasons...

Comment: @Braiam Yeah, that's only for OT.